# Failed to run aapt dump badging: AndroidManifest.xml:16: error: ERROR: missing 'android:name' for uses-permission

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:largeHeap="true" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.customerapp" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <application android:label="CustomerApp" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.file_provider_paths" android:resource="@xml/files_path"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
    
</manifest>
```

I m Not Able To Upload aab File On Google Play Console.

Above is my manifestfile i am not getting why i am getting this issue
please guide need some help
thanks

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle).

Comment: Whats wrong in my manifest file can't able to find

Comment: Could you provide the code that you write to upload aab , just like this [link](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/androidmanifest-xml-16-error-error-missing-android-name-for-uses-permission.129893/).

Comment: Yes Already Provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is displayed on line 16. It's about `usesCleartextTraffic`.
You should remove the line: `<uses-permission android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />` and add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `application` label.

Change to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <application
        android:label="CustomerApp" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    ...
    </application>
    ...
</manifest>
```

For more details about `usesCleartextTraffic`, you can check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic).

Comment: Added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> Line Still Got Same Error.

Comment: Above solution Work .Many Thanks    @ Jianwei Sun - MSFT